# Custom caching using Alamofire

Tags: ios, caching, swift, alamofire

The API I'm consuming has pretty poor caching headers. I want to implement my own caching and was wondering how I would go about it using Alamofire. I'm a total beginner in swift but I think I've gotten the basics. My first thought was to implement the `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` method `URLSession(_:dataTask:willCacheResponse:completionHandler:)` but the Manager object already has it's own delegate and I cannot figure out how I can extend that. I tried debugging the request through Alamofire and it seems the `willCacheResponse` delegate methods are never being fired and that is probably a problem on its own.

My second thought was to extend Manager and add something like `.cachedRequest` but I don't have access to anything through extension and cannot initialize a `Request` object and have very few options.

Coming from JavaScript and being a Promise fan I would love being able to do something like the following:

```
manager.request(Router.UserChannels)
        .checkCache()
        .responseCollection { (_, _, channels: [Channel]?, error: NSError?) in
            completionHandler(channels, error)
        }
```

but I guess it doesn't work that way. I would really love to get some input on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Caching is handled by the underlying URL Loading System, viz `NSURLProtocol`. Using a custom URL protocol, you can modify incoming and outgoing headers as necessary.

Comment: Found this tutorial on using NSURLProtocol in Swift which helps: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift